# Return a specific http status code in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, http-status-codes, http-status-code-503

How do you return **503 Service Unavailable** in Rails for the entire application?

Also, how do you do the same for specific controllers?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

For the entire application:

```
# ApplicationController
before_filter :return_unavailable_status

private
  def return_unavailable_status
    render :nothing => true, :status => :service_unavailable
  end
```

If you wanted a custom error page, you could do:

```
render 'custom_unavailable_page', :status => :service_unavailable
```

If you don't want it for specific controllers:

```
# SomeController
skip_before_filter :return_unavailable_status
```

Comment: To display a custom downpage shall I use, `render "custom_unavailable_page"`, instead of `render :nothing => true`

Comment: @SathishManohar Exactly.  `custom_unavailable_page` would be the name of the view file that you would render.

Comment: Where is that documented? What are the other statuses? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RenderingHelper.html#method-i-render

Comment: @Chloe I don't believe it's documented very well, but here's a list http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render#254-List-of-status-codes-and-their-symbols

Comment: DEPRECATION WARNING: `:nothing` option is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use `head` method to respond with empty response body

Answer (score 113):

You can use `head`

```
head 503
# or
head :service_unavailable
```

Comment: I can use status symbols like :service_unavailable
All statuses: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render#254-List-of-status-codes-and-their-symbols

Comment: @freemanoid: I personally like integer codes better. I already know them. No need to memorize yet another set of values.

Comment: DEPRECATION WARNING: `:nothing` option is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use `head` method to respond with empty response body

Comment: FYI, `head` has been available since Rails 1.2.0. Saying "Rails 5+" implies it's only available in Rails 5 and beyond, which is incorrect.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I would just update the answer to use `head` and if you want to keep the original answer for posterity, just put it below as "Original Answer" or something. I think we can all agree that `head` is the way to go, especially since `render nothing: true` is deprecated on current Rails versions.

Comment: It would help if you said _where to put this_.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
format.any { render :json => {:response => 'Unable to authenticate' },:status => 401  }
```

The `:response` for the HTML response just in case it's accessed from the browser.

The render head 503 does not seem to be working with the above statement.

Comment: This would be bad for SEO. For example, Google would see this as a broken site, not just a site temporarily down but expected to be back up. See this: https://yoast.com/http-503-site-maintenance-seo/

Comment: Might be worth changing this to "Service unavailable" / 503, so it matches with the purpose of the question.  I assume it's the "render head" syntax that isn't working for you, rather than the error code?