# Resource not found errors in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-status-code-404, custom-errors

I know that `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` can be mapped to http 404 error. Is there any other resource in ruby on rails whose non-existence will raise something like
`ResourceName::ResourceNameNotFound` ?

Also are there any errors raised by RoR which are equivalent to 520, 403, 401 ?

Comment: This is called exception handling, there are a few threads that deal with it : http://blog.siami.fr/diving-in-rails-exceptions-handling or this one https://medium.com/rails-ember-beyond/error-handling-in-rails-the-modular-way-9afcddd2fe1b I am not really versed in the subject so I can't really recommend one but if you read a few you will have a good overview

Answer (score 1):

Rails should respond with the proper HTTP error codes in correlation to the conventions of the HTTP protocol. I've worked with Rails for a while and haven't seen any exceptions. You can also raise your own exceptions like this

```
@record = ModelName.find_by(field_name_goes_here: params[:some_parameter_name_goes_here])
    if not @record.blank?
        render "view_file_name_goes_here"
    else
        raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    end
```

This code will cause rails to respond with a 404.
Making a request for a route that has not been defined will also result in a 404.

Other examples:

A syntax error in your code will respond with a 500.

If you are using devise or some other gem for authorization, an unauthorized request will result in rendering a 401. There won't be anything in Rails that would render a 401 out of the box. Remember, all of your requests are defined through routes.rb and it's up to your controllers to decide what response to render and if that response should return an HTTP error code.

This question here provides information on how to render all types of error codes:

[Return a specific http status code in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890351/return-a-specific-http-status-code-in-rails)

If you are looking to debug the http error code I would suggest setting the rails environment configuration to consider all requests as local requests. This will display an understandable error.

[Purpose of "consider_all_requests_local" in config/environments/development.rb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373089/purpose-of-consider-all-requests-local-in-config-environments-development-rb)

Comment: Thanks for elaborate explanation. But my question was more like what errors will cause rails to respond with 500, 403 and 401. As you said in your answer, ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound will cause rails to respond with 404, what errors will cause rails to respond with error codes I've mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

In rails you can raise error when your particular result is mismatch 
like you mention `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` and each error has its meaning like.

```
401 is for NOT_AUTHORIZED
403 is for FORBIDDEN
500 is for server error
```

and there are many other

Answer (score -1):

Missing

```
def index

end
```

will do,

if not,
restart your computer and everything is fine